# Using macros in c program

Tags: c, macros

I've got this silly program with macros, but I don't know what is the failure:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define READ_RX  (1 << 1)
#define WRITE_RX (1 << 2)
#define READ_TX  (1 << 3)
#define WRITE_TX (1 << 4)

#define READ_COMMAND(num) (num == 0) ? (READ_RX) : (READ_TX)
#define WRITE_COMMAND(num) (num == 0) ? (WRITE_RX) : (WRITE_TX)

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    printf("[DEBUG] 0x%04X\n", (READ_COMMAND(0)) | (WRITE_COMMAND(0))); //works fine
    printf("[DEBUG] 0x%04X\n", READ_COMMAND(0) | WRITE_COMMAND(0)); //doesn't work

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
$ ./test
[DEBUG] 0x0006 -> works fine
[DEBUG] 0x0002 -> doesn't work
```

Does anyone know what is the problem?

Best regards.

Comment: He's missing braces and the operator precidence is messing him up.  OP is likely expecting the same output for both printf's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need braces around your whole define.  The second expands to:

```
(num == 0) ? (2) : (8) | (num == 0) ? (1) : (4)
```

notice that the precedence of the `|` is higher than that of the `? :` operator.

Answer (score 5):

Macros just textually replace, what they mean.
i.e.

```
(READ_COMMAND(0)) | (WRITE_COMMAND(0))
```

becomes

```
((num == 0) ? (READ_RX) : (READ_TX)) | ((num == 0) ? (READ_RX) : (READ_TX))
```

whereas

```
READ_COMMAND(0) | WRITE_COMMAND(0)
```

becomes

```
(num == 0) ? (READ_RX) : (READ_TX) | (num == 0) ? (READ_RX) : (READ_TX)
```

Now using the precedence rules, you can see, that this is the same as

```
(num == 0) ? (READ_RX) : ( (READ_TX) | (num == 0) ? (READ_RX) : (READ_TX) )
```